# How to Access the obstacle avoidance Sensor Data of DJI Phantom 4 Pro using Mobile SDK

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I am currently working on DJI-Phantom 4 Pro. Can any one help me in getting the Obstacle avoidance sensor data output from the drone using Mobile-SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention which SDK version you are using but they are similar so this should help.

In the flightController objectyou need to setup an update callback like list:

getIntelligentFlightAssistant().setVisionDetectionStateUpdatedCallback(XXX)

The callback returns updates of type DJIVisionDetectionState.

Within the object is an array of sensors:

List warningSections = djiVisionDetectionState.getDetectionSectors();

Each sensor has a getSystemWarning() method that returns DJIVisionSystemWarning (warning, critical, etc).

Each sensor also has a method getWarningLevel, that returns level1, 2, 3 and 4.

The definition and distance each level represents is in the SDK documentation so I won't repeat it here just in case it changes in the future.